# Can MySQL create a result set by inserting members from a loop?

Tags: mysql

MySQL can do while-loops.

Can it do something like this

```
result_set = <EMPTY SET>

while (condition)
    SELECT foo INTO bar;
    if is_candidate
    then
        add (bar, baz) to result_set
end while

return result_set
```

Is this possible? If so how portable is it?

Context, since I'm sure people will say I'm doing it wrong:

- the declarative way would be to `SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE predicate(whatever)` but in my case `predicate` has `O(n)` running time where `n` is the size of the table
- so the overall query has quadratic running time,
- but searching from known result rows to connected rows using `is_candidate` is `O(1)` and so my pseudocode above would be linear-time overall

(No, this data set isn't ideal for SQL, but it's what I've got to work with.)

Comment: I think you're overthinking things. Why do you think that a simple while loop you construct would perform better than the database's optimizer? Can you share your actual tables, sample data and expected result? It would give some more context to the question.

Comment: @Mureinik It's graph and tree traversal.